# View data of a database in C# form

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm new in C# and I don't know how to view data of MySQL in a form. I have already fixed to create a delete button and an add button but now I also want to view that data in the form. I looked up all kinds of things to get it working, but I just can't get it done. Does anyone know what I need to do to get it work?

Here is how I want to view the data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yixa.png

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
 
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Apparatenlijst : Form
    {
        string MyConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=apparatuur;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
 
        public Apparatenlijst()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
 
        } 
 
        private void Apparatenlijst_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
 
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
            string apparaatt = toevoegg.Text;
 
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            connection.Open();
 
            try
            {
                cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO lijst(apparaatnaam)VALUES(@apparaatnaam)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apparaatnaam", apparaatt);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
 
                    MessageBox.Show("Apparaat succesvol toegevoegd");
                }
            }
        }
 
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        private void verwijder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
            string apparaata = verwijderr.Text;
 
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            connection.Open();
 
            try
            {
                cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM lijst WHERE apparaatnaam=@apparaatnaam";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apparaatnaam", apparaata);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 
            }
           
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                 
                    MessageBox.Show("Apparaat succesvol verwijderd");
                }
            }
 
        }
 
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        private void lvStudents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried anything to display the data?.what was the problem, specifically? What sort of format do you want to display it in? Your request is a little vague.

Comment: Can you make the problem a little clear so that we can help. Better to make it easy to reproduce. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ListView to display the data?

You can call method `MySqlDataAdapter.Fill()` to get the datatable from data source. For this, you need to install Nuget package `MySql.Data`.

Then traverse the datatable and add new `ListViewItem object` to the ListView.

```
string constr = @"connection string";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constr))
{
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * From lijst", conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);

    listView1.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        lvi.Text = row["Field1"].ToString();
        lvi.SubItems.Add(row["Field2"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(row["Field3"].ToString());
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
    listView1.EndUpdate();
}
```

Comment: @ItsLars Does this help you? If yes, please [vote on or accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).